# Product inventory by attribute (visual swatch)

Tags: magento2, backend

I use the "Visual swatch" attribute to offer products in different colors. Most products have the same available colors. For example "bag A" and "bag B" can be sold in red and blue.

Is it possible to disable the blue color for all products ? In my case if I am out of the blue color I cannot produce and offer any product in blue.

Answer (score 1):

Magento doesn't have functionality to cover this functionality. You need to create custom module where will be triggering changes of inventory and updated it for all simple products that have same attribute value.

Comment: Is there a way around this ? I can imagine this being a common issue .. Maybe using visual swatchs isn't the right solution ?

Comment: No way with visual swatches